# How can I use two different hosting for one domain

Tags: php, node.js, dns, hosting

I have two hostings one of them is php supported. And one of them is for node.js.

I want to use node.js only in subdomain or /forum/ directory.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use the same domain on multiple hosts. How would your browser know which one to point to?

Comment: So I should have one server with php and node.js both on it?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using subdomains.

Setup your website's dns like this (replacing the domain and ips):

```
example.com  >  111.111.111.111
www          >  example.com
forum        >  222.222.222.222
```

Answer (score -2):

This could not be the most performant solution but it works well and its really easy to implement.

The idea is to proxy /forum/ for example with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy